# Add Clickable links in Calculation filed in Podio

Tags: javascript, podio

I have made a table with 3 things "Types", "Dates" and "Recordings"

Recordings are external URLs

I want to replace the long URL with the one-word name "Listen" but when I click on "Listen". It will not open any link

Here is my code

```
var dt2= @All of New Call Created On;
var time2= @All of Call - Time in America with nulls;
var type2=@All of Type with nulls;
var smrt2=@All of smrtPhone Number with nulls;
var text2=@All of Call Recording with nulls;
var lines = [];

for(var i = 0; i < smrt2.length; i++){
lines.push(type2[i] + "|" + dt2[i] + "|" + '"[Listen](http://+text2[i]"');
};

"Types | Dates | Recordings \n" +
"--- | --- | --- \n" + lines.join("\n")
```

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful to add your `screenshot` your question not in a separate link

Comment: Hi Joseph, I added a screenshot, but It automatic convert into link

Comment: I edit it for you accept it

Comment: How you did this?

Comment: from  edit mode, there is an image `icon` in the toolbar

Comment: I also added image from that but why my image goes to the link

Comment: i don't know really when i add it always it popup to me